# Keeping up to date a subtree of other project

Tags: git, git-merge, git-subtree

In my project I am using several libraries grouped in a /Libs folder (relative to the root of my project tree). I want to use a library in my project. But I do not like to import whole library's repo as it contains a lot of unnecessary stuff - docs, examples, tools, etc. I want to import just a 'src' folder. One more important thing: I want to use subtree, rather than subrepo.

What I did (where a_lib is a name of library I want to use):

```
git remote add a_lib https://github.com/xxx/a_lib.git
git fetch a_lib
git checkout -b dependencies/a_lib a_lib/master
git subtree split --prefix=src --annotate="[a_lib] " --rejoin -b subtrees/a_lib
git checkout master
git subtree add --prefix=Libs/a_lib --squash subtrees/a_lib
```

So far so good. With these commands I pulled a_lib sources, extracted 'src' directory from library source tree into a separate branch. Finally I added library's 'src' folder as Libs/a_lib directory of my primary project.

Since I imported library into my project the library has updated. I would like to pull new changes and merge them with those I did in the library code.

I tried these commands (doing them on other computer, so some steps repeat)

```
git remote add a_lib https://github.com/xxx/a_lib.git
git fetch a_lib
git checkout -b dependencies/a_lib a_lib/master
git subtree split --prefix=src --annotate="[a_lib] " --rejoin -b subtrees/a_lib
git checkout master
git subtree merge --prefix=Libs/STM32generic --squash subtrees/stm32generic
```

The last command fail with this output

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '62d6171eb30af14351671c483f4e0a233df24e20^0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
could not rev-parse split hash 62d6171eb30af14351671c483f4e0a233df24e20 from commit 66375945cbe689c6864d3a0adba53bdbe0c0f86c
Can't squash-merge: 'Libs/a_lib' was never added.
```

I am quite new to git, so I could not figure our myself what is wrong here. Can anybody help me merge library changes?